# Consulta en MySQL para obtener porcentaje sobre dos fechas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Soy nueva en la parte de base de datos quisiera saber como puedo lograr lo siguiente.
Tengo una tabla de tareas donde tengo 4 columnas que son. Fecha Asignada esta es la fecha en que se asigno la tarea, fecha de inicio de la tarea, fecha de entrega y por la ultimo una de progreso que seria ejemplo 10% 20% 30%.
¿ Como puedo realizar una consulta donde me calcule que progreso %  debe llevar cierta tarea y que a eso me haga el insert con ese porcentaje en la columna progreso ?

Esta intentando algo asi.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (DAY, Tr_FechaInicio, Tr_FechaFinal) AS Diferencia_Dias FROM tareas
```

se que debo dividir ( 100 / Diferencia_Dias) y esto me dará el resultado de cuanto equivale un día a un porcentaje sobre ese 100%.
Muchas gracias a la persona que me logre ayudar ya que estoy un poco confundida.

Comment: Necesitas multiplicar el resultado de la división por el número de días desde el inicio hasta una fecha de referencia, que normalmente sería la fecha actual.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no se como guardar ese valor de esa división para luego dividirlo, no se como se guardan valores si es igual que en codigo como int n1 = 100 / diferenciadias..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar la función `DATEDIFF` para conseguir la diferencia de días que hay entre una fecha y otra

la estructura que tienes es la siguiente

tabla: tareas

- **Tr_FechaInicio**: fecha cuando tiene que iniciar la tarea
- **Tr_FechaFinal**: fecha cuando tiene que finalizar la tarea

**la lógica seria la siguiente:**

tienes una cantidad de días para terminar la tarea asignada ese es el 100%

la diferencia entre el día que debió iniciar la tarea al dia actual es el progreso que debería llevar la tarea

lo que se necesita hacer es saber es que porcentaje significa desde que inicio la tarea al día actual

```sql
SELECT 
  dias_faltantes_para_terminar / dias_totales_para_terminar * 100 as porcentaje_faltante,
  100 - (dias_faltantes_para_terminar / dias_totales_para_terminar * 100) as porcentaje_progreso
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaFinal, Tr_FechaInicio)+1 AS 'dias_totales_para_terminar',
    DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaFinal, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)+1 AS 'dias_faltantes_para_terminar'
  FROM tareas
) as result
```

**Datos de prueba**

Tr_FechaInicio = 2020-01-01

Tr_FechaFinal= 2020-01-30

Fecha actual = 2020-01-14

---

**Proceso**

---

Días totales para terminar = 30 (días de deferencia entre el inicio y el fin)

Días faltantes para terminar = 16 (días de diferencia entre el día actual y el fin)

Días de progreso = 14 `(30 - 16)`

Porcentaje faltante = 53.34 `(16 / 30 * 100)`

Porcentaje progreso = 46.66 `(100 - (16 / 30 * 100))` o segunda opción, mismo resultado `(14 / 30 * 100)`

---

*resultado*

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>porcentaje_faltante </td>
        <td>porcentaje_progreso </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>51.7241</td>
        <td>48.2759</td>     
    </tr>
</table>`
```

Comment: Esos días_faltantes_para_terminar / dias_totales_para_terminar son columnas que deberían estar en la tabla o de donde saldrían esos valores que obtiene cada uno ??

Comment: esas columnas son que se calculan en el momento que ejecutas la consulta, no necesitan estar en la tabla, les puse ese nombre para que sea algo descriptivo y fácil de entender

Comment: Así calcularía el % faltante, cuando PO require % progreso.

Comment: le puedes agregar 100 - (formula), te deje el ejemplo en mi respuesta (la modifique)

Comment: La verdad lo resultados que me esta arrojando son, 75.0000, 116.6667 y 56.6667 y no entiendo de donde.

Comment: A la editaste,  ok ya revisare.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para corregir un detalle con la consulta y ser mucho mas claro, con ejemplos, espero haberte ayudado, si te sirvió no olvides poner la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Me funciono genial. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Como puedo insertar esos resultados en una columna progreso de la misma tabla ??

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321984/llenar-columna-con-los-resultados-de-un-select-en-la-misma-tabla