# Llenar columna con los resultados de un select en la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una sentencia select donde calcule un porcentaje de unas tareas y necesito que esos valores se inserten en una columna Progreso de la misma tabla donde realice el select mi código es el siguiente.

Esta es mi consulta select y se crea la columna temporal progreso

```
SELECT 
    100 - dias_faltantes_para_terminar / dias_totales_para_terminar * 100 AS Progreso
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaInicio, Tr_FechaFinal) AS 'dias_totales_para_terminar',
    DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Tr_FechaFinal) AS 'dias_faltantes_para_terminar'

  FROM tareas
) AS result
```

En este update necesito que se ingresen los resultados de la sentencia select

```
UPDATE tareas
SET Tr_Porcentaje = /*Aca como ingreso los resultados del select */
WHERE Tr_Id > 0
```

Comment: Al menos según lo que muestras, solo deberías trasladar la fórmula al `SET`, así: `SET Tr_Porcentaje = 100 - DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Tr_FechaFinal) / DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaInicio, Tr_FechaFinal) * 100`

Comment: Muchas gracias patricio asi lo hice hace unos minutos igual gracias por tu comentario